# Is there a way to visualize an ItemTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl that has a fairly complex ItemTemplate which allows the user to edit an Order. Unfortunately the design surface in Visual Studio does not show the ItemTemplate so I don't get an instant feedback of the changes I make. Is there a way to visualize the ItemTemplate in Visual Studio? Here's the structure of my control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Orders, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!-- Fairly complex form here -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've just copied the contents of the DataTemplate into a new WPFControl. Sometimes I've had to use some dummy data to view it properly, but for the most part it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you have complicated UI, it might be better to refactor it out into a `UserControl`, which you can then visualise normally in Visual Studio.

Alternatively, I believe that Expression Blend (if you have access to that) allows you to visualise the `DataTemplate` directly

Comment: The problem with Expression Blend is that once you use it, you will never want to write XAML any other way. It's a wonderful tool.

Comment: Good suggestion on refactoring out as a UserControl. As for Expression Blend, I could not figure out how to visualize the ItemTemplate - but I am not an experienced Blend user.